# bubble sort doesn´t return a sorted array

Tags: lisp

which is a bubble sort made of if´s only. This is my first code in Lisp, that´s why I didn´t use the function 'loop', or 'DO' because i don´t know how to use them.

```
(defun bubble()
    ((let (array (make-array '(4))))
          (setf (aref array 0) 7)
          (setf (aref array 1) 2)
          (setf (aref array 2) 4)
          (setf (aref array 3) 5))     
    (setf i 0)
    (defun c1 (IF (<= i (- n 1))
         (progn (setq j 1)
               (defun c2 (j) (IF (<= j (- n i))
                                     (progn(IF (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                           (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                   (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                   (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                   (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))

                                                 (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))
                                            );if
                                     );progn

                                     (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))) 
                                 );if
               );c2   
          );progn
         array();
        ) 
     );c1
);bubble
```

the problem is that it doesn´t print the array, it just prints the word BUBBLE. Someone told on a previous post that defun always return the name of the function, but without the defun how could i create a function named bubble that returns an array???

Comment: Nested DEFUN is wrong. Use LABELS or FLET for local functions.

Comment: You may also want to indent and format the code properly to make it readable.

Answer (score 3):

I think that we have to take this a bit apart.

If you use proper indentation, you do not need to annotate your parentheses, which makes the overall coding experience much nicer:

```
(defun bubble ()
  ((let (array (make-array '(4))))
   (setf (aref array 0) 7)
   (setf (aref array 1) 2)
   (setf (aref array 2) 4)
   (setf (aref array 3) 5))     
  (setf i 0)
  (defun c1 (IF (<= i (- n 1))
                (progn (setq j 1)
                       (defun c2 (j) (if (<= j (- n i))
                                         (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                    (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                           (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                           (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                           (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                                    (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                         (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))
                array
                ())))
```

Now, there are some syntactic errors.  I don't know how this could compile without at least a warning.

Your `defun c1 ...` form is missing a parameter list.

```
(defun bubble ()
  ((let (array (make-array '(4))))
   (setf (aref array 0) 7)
   (setf (aref array 1) 2)
   (setf (aref array 2) 4)
   (setf (aref array 3) 5))     
  (setf i 0)
  (defun c1 ()
    (if (<= i (- n 1))
        (progn (setq j 1)
               (defun c2 (j) (if (<= j (- n i))
                                 (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                            (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                   (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                   (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                   (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                            (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                 (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))
        array
        ())))
```

Your `let` form is entirely in disarray.  `Let` can create more than one binding, so you need to wrap the bindings in a list.  A `let` form is also not a valid operator.  Its body needs to be inside the form.  The bindings only have the scope of the body.

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (make-array '(4))))
    (setf (aref array 0) 7)
    (setf (aref array 1) 2)
    (setf (aref array 2) 4)
    (setf (aref array 3) 5)
    (setf i 0)
    (defun c1 ()
      (if (<= i (- n 1))
          (progn (setq j 1)
                 (defun c2 (j) (if (<= j (- n i))
                                   (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                              (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                     (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                     (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                     (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                              (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                   (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))
          array
          ()))))
```

Your `if` form in `c1` has four arguments, but `if` takes only three.  I'll remove the `()` at the end, which seems quite nonsensical:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (make-array '(4))))
    (setf (aref array 0) 7)
    (setf (aref array 1) 2)
    (setf (aref array 2) 4)
    (setf (aref array 3) 5)
    (setf i 0)
    (defun c1 ()
      (if (<= i (- n 1))
          (progn (setq j 1)
                 (defun c2 (j) (if (<= j (- n i))
                                   (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                              (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                     (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                     (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                     (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                              (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                   (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))
          array))))
```

Don't try to nest `defun`s.  That does not work like you think it does.  It will still define global function definitions, just at a different time.  For local function definitions, use `labels` or `flet`:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (make-array '(4))))
    (setf (aref array 0) 7)
    (setf (aref array 1) 2)
    (setf (aref array 2) 4)
    (setf (aref array 3) 5)
    (setf i 0)
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (<= i (- n 1))
                   (progn (setq j 1)
                          (labels ((c2 (j)
                                     (if (<= j (- n i))
                                         (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                    (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                           (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                           (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                           (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                                    (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                         (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))))
                   array))))))
```

Let's make that array initialization a bit shorter:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5))))
    (setf i 0)
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (<= i (- n 1))
                   (progn (setq j 1)
                          (labels ((c2 (j)
                                     (if (<= j (- n i))
                                         (progn (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                    (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                                           (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                                           (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                                           (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                                    (c2 (setq j (+ j 1)))))
                                         (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))))
                   array))))))
```

`Aux`, `n`, `j`, and `i` are not defined.  By setting them, you create new global variables that might or might not be *special*.  Don't to that.  First create bindings for them with `let`.  Besides, you do not need a `progn` for a single form.

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4)
        (i 0)
        (aux 0))
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (<= i (- n 1))
                   (let ((j 1))
                     (labels ((c2 (j)
                                (if (<= j (- n i))
                                    (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                        (progn (setq aux (aref array (+ j 1)))
                                               (setq (aref array (+ j 1)) (aref array j))
                                               (setq (aref array j) aux)
                                               (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                        (c2 (setq j (+ j 1))))
                                    (c1 (setq i (+ i 1))))))))
                   array))))))
```

I think that we now have covered the syntactic issues.  Let's go to simplification.

Swapping two (or more) places can be done with `rotatef`, you do not need to create temporary variables for that.  There is a function `1+` for adding 1 to something.

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4)
        (i 0))
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (<= i (- n 1))
                   (let ((j 1))
                     (labels ((c2 (j)
                                (if (<= j (- n i))
                                    (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (1+ j)))
                                        (progn (rotatef (aref array j)
                                                        (aref array (1+ j)))
                                               (c2 (setq j (1+ j))))
                                        (c2 (setq j (1+ j))))
                                    (c1 (setq i (1+ i))))))))
                   array))))))
```

Increasing the value of a variable and storing it back into that variable is done with `incf`:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4)
        (i 0))
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (<= i (- n 1))
                   (let ((j 1))
                     (labels ((c2 (j)
                                (if (<= j (- n i))
                                    (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (1+ j)))
                                        (progn (rotatef (aref array j)
                                                        (aref array (1+ j)))
                                               (c2 (incf j)))
                                        (c2 (incf j)))
                                    (c1 (incf i)))))))
                   array))))))
```

Instead of testing with `<=` against *one less* than an integer, test with `<` against the integer itself:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4)
        (i 0))
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (< i n)
                   (let ((j 1))
                     (labels ((c2 (j)
                                (if (< j n)
                                    (if (> (aref array j) (aref array (1+ j)))
                                        (progn (rotatef (aref array j)
                                                        (aref array (1+ j)))
                                               (c2 (incf j)))
                                        (c2 (incf j)))
                                    (c1 (incf i)))))))
                   array))))))
```

Instead of repeating the inner call to `c2`, move the thing you want to do before one level out.

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4)
        (i 0))
    (labels ((c1 ()
               (if (< i n)
                   (let ((j 1))
                     (labels ((c2 (j)
                                (if (< j n)
                                    (progn
                                      (when (> (aref array j)
                                               (aref array (1+ j)))
                                        (rotatef (aref array j)
                                                 (aref array (1+ j))))
                                      (c2 (incf j)))
                                    (c1 (incf i)))))))
                   array))))))
```

Your inner functions are never called.  Let's fix that, and sanitize the parameter handling:

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4))
    (labels ((c1 (i)
               (if (< i n)
                   (labels ((c2 (j)
                              (if (< j n)
                                  (progn
                                    (when (> (aref array j)
                                             (aref array (1+ j)))
                                      (rotatef (aref array j)
                                               (aref array (1+ j))))
                                    (c2 (1+ j)))
                                  (c1 (1+ i)))))
                     (c2 1))
                   array)))
      (c1 0))))
```

`J` should run not from 1 but from `i`.  `I` and `j` should only run up to below `(1- n)`, because `(1+ j)` needs to be a valid array index.

```
(defun bubble ()
  (let ((array (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5)))
        (n 4))
    (labels ((c1 (i)
               (if (< i (1- n))
                   (labels ((c2 (j)
                              (if (< j (1- n))
                                  (progn
                                    (when (> (aref array j)
                                             (aref array (1+ j)))
                                      (rotatef (aref array j)
                                               (aref array (1+ j))))
                                    (c2 (1+ j)))
                                  (c1 (1+ i)))))
                     (c2 i))
                   array)))
      (c1 0))))
```

I think that this works now, as long as the array length is smaller than your stack limit.

It would make sense not to define an array to be sorted inside the function, but to pass it as an argument.  That way, you can actually use the function to sort any array (actually any vector, i. e. one-dimensional array).  `N` is the length of that vector.

```
(defun bubble (vector)
  (let ((n (length vector)))
    (labels ((c1 (i)
               (if (< i (1- n))
                   (labels ((c2 (j)
                              (if (< j (1- n))
                                  (progn
                                    (when (> (aref vector j)
                                             (aref vector (1+ j)))
                                      (rotatef (aref vector j)
                                               (aref vector (1+ j))))
                                    (c2 (1+ j)))
                                  (c1 (1+ i)))))
                     (c2 i))
                   vector)))
      (c1 0))))

;;; For example, call with (bubble (copy-seq #(7 2 4 5))). It should return #(2 4 5 7).
```

In order not to modify the vector passed as an argument, use `copy-seq` to make a copy prior to sorting.  It is always potentially surprising to have a function modify its arguments.  We also do not run into potential trouble with the modification of literal data.

```
(defun bubble (unsorted-vector)
  (let ((vector (copy-seq unsorted-vector))
        (n (length unsorted-vector)))
    (labels ((c1 (i)
               (if (< i (1- n))
                   (labels ((c2 (j)
                              (if (< j (1- n))
                                  (progn
                                    (when (> (aref vector j)
                                             (aref vector (1+ j)))
                                      (rotatef (aref vector j)
                                               (aref vector (1+ j))))
                                    (c2 (1+ j)))
                                  (c1 (1+ i)))))
                     (c2 i))
                   vector)))
      (c1 0))))

;;; For example, call with (bubble #(7 2 4 5)). It should return #(2 4 5 7).
```

In order to remove the stack limitation, let's transform this into loops.

```
(defun bubble (unsorted-vector)
  (let ((vector (copy-seq unsorted-vector))
        (n (length unsorted-vector)))
    (loop :for i :below (1- n)
      :do (loop :for j :from i :below (1- n)
            :do (when (> (aref vector j)
                         (aref vector (1+ j)))
                  (rotatef (aref vector j)
                           (aref vector (1+ j))))))
    vector))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function after you define it.

Comment: @mp do i have to call the function with the array as an argument, like bubble(7 2 4 5);???

Comment: The bubble function takes no parameters, the array to sort is defined inside the function body.